# How to get File from R.raw

Tags: android, file

I need to get an array of bytes of a File, so I need to know the length of the file. 
How can I get a file from the assets or raw directory ?

It seems that the most normal is to get the InputStream, but then can't get the length of the file.

How can I File from R.raw ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, place your testfile.txt file into **res/raw/**

2, get this file like below

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.TestFile);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        stream.write(length);
    }
    return stream.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: It works, but I'm getting a clicking noise at the start of playing the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

```
file:///android_asset/yourfile
android.resource://package_name/raw/yourfile
```