# How to load *.mat file in raw folder of android

Tags: android, file-io, android-resources, ioexception, mat-file

I try to load a `.mat` file in Android 4.4, using JMatIO.

It worked well when the `.mat` file was in external storage, but it didn't work when the file was in the app's `raw` folder. Currently, the application can not find any `*.mat` files. The log just prints the message, "fail to load matrix file".

Below is the code I'm using:

```
try {
        mfr = new MatFileReader("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/rm.mat");
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "fail to load matrix file");
        System.exit(0);
}
if (mfr != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Success to load matrix file");
}
```

How can I load the file successfully?

Comment: Which version of Android is this? What kind of an error are you getting? Please add it to your question. And while you're at it, please remove the [tag:mat] tag since your question has nothing to do with `OpenCV`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not accessing the file properly with this code:

```
mfr = new MatFileReader("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/rm.mat");
```

From what I understand, you're trying to access a file which is located in you `\res\raw\` folder. This is usually done using `R.raw.filname_without_extension`. In your case you should try:

```
mfr = new MatFileReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.rm), MatFileType.Regular);
```

If you are still having problems, take a look at these resources:

1. Documentation: [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

   > **Access to Original Files**
   >
   > While uncommon, you might need access your original files and
   >   directories. If you do, then saving your files in `res/` won't work for
   >   you, because the only way to read a resource from `res/` is with the
   >   resource ID. Instead, you can save your resources in the `assets/`
   >   directory.
   >
   > Files saved in the `assets/` directory are not given a resource ID, so
   >   you can't reference them through the `R` class or from XML resources.
   >   Instead, you can query files in the `assets/` directory like a normal
   >   file system and read raw data using [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).
   >
   > However, if all you require is the ability to read raw data (such as a
   >   video or audio file), then save the file in the `res/raw/` directory and
   >   read a stream of bytes using [`openRawResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int))
2. JMatIO Source: [The relevant MatFileReader signature](https://github.com/codemercenary/JMatIO/blob/master/src/main/java/ca/mjdsystems/jmatio/io/MatFileReader.java#L187)
3. SO Question: [R.raw.anything cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884268/r-raw-anything-cannot-be-resolved)
4. SO Question: [How to get File from R.raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270528/how-to-get-file-from-r-raw)
5. SO Question: [How to read file from res/raw by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name)